# How to Create Unlimited Dynamic texBox with their TextChange Event in GridView in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to ask that how can I create unlimited `TextBox` With their `TextChange Event`in `GridView` in ASP.NET without using This in `GridView` Because it would create Limited Number of `TextBox` with their `TextChange` Event  :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Debit"> 
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDebit1" onkeydown="tabE(this,event)" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtDebit1_TextChanged" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate> 
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating your question a bit more...from above example it will create unlimited textboxes automatically and according to the no. of records displayed in `GridView`. And each row will have its own text change event which you can find with the help of Gridview instance in textChange event

Comment: Yup , I have Create unlimited Columns with TextBox But unable to  Attach TextChange event uniquely with every Textbox of a Column .

Comment: Can we Attach  Anonymous Event with a TextBox. Where we can Do Some Coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will call the `TextBox` `OnChange` method for every control and will give you instance of the one is fired postback.

```
protected void txtDebit1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow)((TextBox)sender).NamingContainer);
        //NamingContainer return the container that the control sits in
        TextBox ctrl= (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDebit1");
        ctrk.Text = "SomeValue";
    }
```

Comment: Like that i Have to Create Static Methods for Every Textbox But Again it would be limited in number ...

Comment: Why you are creating Static methods for every textbox. Try above this will be fire uniquely for every textbox inside gridview

Comment: No...This is what First line is doing Getting the control's instance which has fired the postback. Set a debug point and try it...it will work